# Matching booking data to opportunity data

Tags: excel, matching

I need some help with matching data. Basically I have 2 files. One is a data set off all accounts that I have and the second is a booking file with accounts who have booked. I basically need to match the booking data to my opportunity file so that it shows me which accounts have booked.

There is a unique identifier in each file (an account number for example) so this is what I need to match

All help is much appreciated

Many thanks

Comment: Are the files in order?  What have you tried?

Comment: I have them on 2 separate tabs. I've tried vlookup but couldn't get it to work. I then tried countif but didn't seem to get any luck. The vlookup would be handy because as well as match it would also allow me to display another column that could show me something like booked date for example